# Changing a Global Variable to a Reference Parameter C++

Tags: c++, recursion

So, after a lot of research on many sites, I finally broke down and made an account. I'm new and also new to programming so please be keep that in mind :)

I am making the classic example of recursion by making a program that uses Euclid's Method for greatest common divisor. I also need to keep track of how many times the function calls itself/how many times the recursion happens.

I have the program working perfectly, but I am using a global (very bad!) variable to hold the count of recursion. I need to replace the global variable with a reference parameter passed through my gcd function, but I am *very* poor in my understanding of how that works. That is my question. Could someone please show me how I can remove the global variable by using a reference parameter? Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype functions
int gcd(int first, int second);

//Global varibles
//Depth will count how many times the recursive function runs.
int depth = 0;

int main ()
{
    //variables
    int firstNum, secondNum;
    do
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Euclid's method for finding the GCD." << endl << "To quit, enter 0 for either number." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the first number:";
        cin >> firstNum;
        cout << "Enter the second number:";
        cin >> secondNum;
        //The program quits if the user enters 0. If this happens, the program won't bother with running the recursive function.
        if (firstNum != 0 && secondNum != 0)
        {
            cout << "The GCD of " << firstNum << " and " <<secondNum << " is ";
            cout << gcd(firstNum, secondNum) << "." << endl;
            cout << "The recursive calculation required a depth of " << depth <<"." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (firstNum != 0 && secondNum != 0); //Program quits on 0 being entered
    return (0);
}
//Recursive function. It will call itself until second number is 0.
int gcd(int first, int second)
    {
        if(second != 0) 
        {
            depth++;
            return gcd(second, first % second);
        }
        else
            return first;
    }
```

Comment: this should be posted to the code review section, but to save you time as you're getting rid of a global which is a good cause, I'll give you the function declaration for a reference parameter:    int gcd (int first, int second, int& depth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing that parameter by reference.

```
int main ()
{
    //variables
    int firstNum, secondNum;
    int depth = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Euclid's method for finding the GCD." << endl << "To quit, enter 0 for either number." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the first number:";
        cin >> firstNum;
        cout << "Enter the second number:";
        cin >> secondNum;
        //The program quits if the user enters 0. If this happens, the program won't bother with running the recursive function.
        if (firstNum != 0 && secondNum != 0)
        {
            cout << "The GCD of " << firstNum << " and " <<secondNum << " is ";
            cout << gcd(firstNum, secondNum, depth) << "." << endl;
            cout << "The recursive calculation required a depth of " << depth <<"." << endl;
        }
    }
    while (firstNum != 0 && secondNum != 0); //Program quits on 0 being entered
    return (0);
}
//Recursive function. It will call itself until second number is 0.
int gcd(int first, int second, int &depth)
    {
        if(second != 0) 
        {
            depth++;
            return gcd(second, first % second, depth);
        }
        else
            return first;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the reference parameter to the function definition.

```
int gcd(int first, int second, int& depth)
    {
        if(second != 0) 
        {
            depth++;
            return gcd(second, first % second, depth);
        }
        else
            return first;
    }
```

Then declare `depth` as a local variable in `main()`, initialize it to `0`, and call `gcd(firstNum, secondNum, depth)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int gcd(int first, int second, int& depth)
{
    if(second != 0) 
    {
        ++depth;
        return gcd(second, first % second, depth);
    }
    else
    {
        return first;
    }
}
```

You have to call it little bit different tho. Create new int, initialize it to `0` and pass as third argument. After this is done it will hold depth.

Answer (score 1):

add depth to prototype parameters to (note the reference notation) it does not need to be named depth.

```
int gcd(int first, int second, int &depth);
```

remove the global definition for depth.

add depth to local variables

```
int firstNum, secondNum, depth=0;
```

add depth to first call (this passes by reference)

```
std::cout << gcd(firstNum, secondNum, depth) << "." << std::endl;
```

add depth to function definition

```
int gcd(int first, int second, int &depth)
```

add depth to recursive call

```
return gcd(second, first % second, depth);
```